# Oracle SQL Developer - naming of new files

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

1. When in Oracle SQL Developer, we click on New -> SQL File, the file that is opened up is with a default name Untitled.sql. Now if you plan to open a lot of files/tables/objects, entire top pane can be occupied leading to need to scrolling. To avoid that, is there an option which allows to change the default suggested name from untitled.sql to lets say .sql (eg:- 1.sql). 
   Even though the option to change the default name while opening is always there, it would be nice if there is a setting to change the default suggestion as well.
2. Also if a file/editor is already opened, is there a way to rename it. Simple right click, doesn't offer a rename option

Many thanks!

Comment: You don't seem to be setting (or wanting, by default) a meaningful name; so are you sure you actually want to create a file, not just a worksheet (which you can still save later to a file, of course)? I think the answer to both of your questions is 'no', incidentally...

Comment: 1. If you do your work in a sql worksheet (with db connection) and save, the file defaults to the name of the connection, followed by a # if there's already a file by that name.
2. File > Save As is as close as we have to rename.

Comment: Thanks Alex and Jeff, the suggestions you mentioned are useful and informative. And Jeff's answer provides the information that the feature that i was looking for doesn't exist, but a close alternative exists. i 'll go ahead with the worksheet option. Thank you both!